# field values getting changed in awk

Tags: regex, bash, if-statement, awk, filesystems

This is quite confusing, so I am going to show all my steps in building to to issue:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS == /\s\s\s\s/ } ; 
    {
    if ( NF == 0 )
        next
    else
        {{ print "-------------NR = " NR "-----------------------NF = " NF }
        for (i = 0; i <= NF; i++)
            {{ print ( i, $i )}    }
        }
    }' 200_Undercounter_Series.txt > new.txt
```

Produces the desired results (I have only included the records that are relevant):

```
-------------NR = 9-----------------------NF = 7
0                                 1.         3510090               Shelf Guard  (See SN Breaks)
1 1.
2 3510090
3 Shelf
4 Guard
5 (See
6 SN
7 Breaks)
-------------NR = 10-----------------------NF = 6
0                                      3515980               Shelf Guard  (See SN Breaks)
1 3515980
2 Shelf
3 Guard
4 (See
5 SN
6 Breaks)
```

Notice the values for fields 1 and 2 of record 9, and field 1 for record 10. My desire is to separate these 2 records from the rest of the file, so I zone in on the value of field 2 for record 9 as such:

```
if ( NF == 0 )
    next
else
    {{ print "-------------NR = " NR "-----------------------NF = " NF }
    for (i = 0; i <= NF; i++)
        {if ( $2 = /[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/)
            { print ( ">>", i, $i)}
        else
            { print ( i, $i )}
        }
    }
}' 200_Undercounter_Series.txt > new.txt
```

And I receive these results:

```
-------------NR = 9-----------------------NF = 7
>> 0 1. 1 Shelf Guard (See SN Breaks)
1 1.
2 0
3 Shelf
4 Guard
5 (See
6 SN
7 Breaks)
-------------NR = 10-----------------------NF = 6
>> 0 3515980 1 Guard (See SN Breaks)
>> 1 3515980
>> 2 1
>> 3 Guard
>> 4 (See
>> 5 SN
>> 6 Breaks)
```

Notice not only that the '>>' indicators are on the record NOT specified ($2 = /regex/), but field 2 in record 9 is now = 0!!!

There is no other code in my program at this point. What am I missing here?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You're assigning to $2

```
    {if ( $2 = /[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/)
             ^
```

You want the regex operator instead

```
    {if ( $2 ~ /[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/)
             ^
```

Comment: Thanks Glenn! I was going off the assumption of '==' for assignment and '=' for comparison, but that did it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

two problems I saw in your codes:

- `BEGIN { FS == /\s\s\s\s/ }` should be `FS='.....'`
- in your if statement you have `if ($2 = /[0-9]..../)` you want actually `if($2~/[0-9].../)`

`==` is for checking left part and right part, if they are equal.

`=` is variable assignment.

`~` is for regex matching.